# Генерация вложенных Id-классов в Hibernate Tools

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Есть база, в которой много таблиц не имеют Primary Key. Использую автогенератор Entity из Hibernate Tools, который для таких таблиц генерирует отдельный Id-класс. В итоге на 100 таблиц без PK получается 200 классов.

Можно ли настроить автогенерацию Id-классов таким образом, чтобы эти классы генерировались как вложенные для Entity этих таблиц?

Comment: а что мешает во все таблицы добавить суррогатный ключ , который будет "genereted by default as identity" ?

Comment: @aleshka-batman : Наличие нескольких сотен таблиц с уже существующими данными. В части таблиц PK уже есть, в части - нету, и где-то он вообще составной (что приводит к генерации id-class, но уже не суррогатного). Вручную обрабатывать все таблицы - сомнительное удовольствие.